# tkinter frame size in notebook

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm creating a notebook with two tabs, in each tab I create a frame of fixed sizes.

```
height = ...
width = ...
notebook = ttk.Notebook(parent, height=height, width=width, padding=0, style="my_nb_style.TNotebook")
notebook_tabs = {'Tab 1': None, 'Tab 2': None}
for _ in notebook_tabs:
    notebook_tabs[_] = ttk.Frame(notebook, width=600, height=300, style='my_frame_style.TFrame')
    notebook.add(notebook_tabs[_], text=_, padding='0m')
```

And then I have a problem, since for the first tab the `width` and `height` values are applied, but for the second one they are not.

```
for _ in notebook_tabs:
    widget = notebook_tabs[_]
    widget.update()
    print(f"{_}: {widget.winfo_width()}x{widget.winfo_height()})
```

It will print:

```
Tab 1: 600x300
Tab 2: 1x1
```

Using the `*.grid_propagate(0)` method doesn't solve this problem.
Please tell me why this situation occurs and how to defeat it.

Comment: It's probably just because the other frames aren't visible.

Comment: When I run your code *all* the tabs are `1x1`.

Comment: Hi @bryan-oakley! Thank you for your attention! 
In the same project I'm making a notebook (let it be Notebook_A) at a higher level, it has 3 tabs, and there all sizes work out correctly. The problematic notebook is located in one of the tabs in Notebook_A. And it is created with the same code. But he has problems with sizes.

Comment: Hi @martineau! Thank you for your attention too! I have a lot of code. The notebook is in a separate frame, the frame is in ... and so on. I didn't share everything. Therefore, when you run the given piece of code, you get what you got. My question was not "what code should I write to make it work right here", but rather "how can I effectively manage the size of widgets"

Comment: Why is the reported size before you add other widgets important? If you run the program, do the frames not fill the tabs?

Comment: Yes, the frames don't fill the tabs. And in addition, there are other elements within the frames that should be sized based on the size of their parent. Here is the problem.